# Optimizing Bitwise Logic

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation, 64-bit

In my code the following lines are currently the hotspot:

```
int table1[256] = /*...*/;
int table2[512] = /*...*/;
int table3[512] = /*...*/;

int* result = /*...*/;
for(int r = 0; r < r_end; ++r)
{
    std::uint64_t bits = bit_reader.value(); // 64 bits, no assumption regarding bits.

    // The get_ functions are table lookups from the highest word of the bits variable.

    struct entry
    {
        int sign_offset : 5;
        int r_offset    : 4;        
        int x           : 7;        
    };

    // NOTE: We are only interested in the highest word in the bits variable.

    entry e;
    if(is_in_table1(bits)) // branch prediction should work well here since table1 will be hit more often than 2 or 3, and 2 more often than 3.
        e = reinterpret_cast<const entry&>(table1[get_table1_index(bits)]);
    else if(is_in_table2(bits))
        e = reinterpret_cast<const entry&>(table2[get_table2_index(bits)]);
    else
        e = reinterpret_cast<const entry&>(table3[get_table3_index(bits)]);

    r                 += e.r_offset; // r is 18 bits, top 14 bits are always 0.
    int x              = e.x; // x is 14 bits, top 18 bits are always 0.        
    int sign_offset    = e.sign_offset;

    assert(sign_offset <= 16 && sign_offset > 0);

    // The following is the hotspot.

    int sign    = 1 - (bits >> (63 - sign_offset) & 0x2);
    (*result++) = ((x << 18) * sign) | r; // 32 bits

    // End of hotspot

    bit_reader.skip(sign_offset); // sign_offset is the last bit used.
}
```

Though I haven't figured out how to further optimize this, maybe something from [intrinsics for Operations at Bit-Granularity](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/cpp/lin/intref_cls/common/intref_bk_avx2_manipulate.htm), [`__shiftleft128`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/szzkhewe%28v=vs.80%29) or [`_rot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5e2f3sc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) could be useful?

Note that I am also doing processing of the resulting data on the GPU, so the important thing is to get something into `result` which the GPU then can use to calculate the correct.

Suggestions?

EDIT:

Added table look-up.

EDIT:

```
            int sign = 1 - (bits >> (63 - e.sign_offset) & 0x2);
000000013FD6B893  and         ecx,1Fh  
000000013FD6B896  mov         eax,3Fh  
000000013FD6B89B  sub         eax,ecx  
000000013FD6B89D  movzx       ecx,al  
000000013FD6B8A0  shr         r8,cl  
000000013FD6B8A3  and         r8d,2  
000000013FD6B8A7  mov         r14d,1  
000000013FD6B8AD  sub         r14d,r8d
```

Comment: What's sign_offset?  Is it - or can it be made - a compile time constant?

Comment: It is not a compile constant, it is looked up in a table depending on the bits before the sign bit in msb order. The `sign_offset` simply tells which bit (index) is the sign bit from the msb/left in `bits`.

Comment: So, can you store pre-calculated sign values directly in the table alongside the sign_offsets?  Is sign_offset itself needed?  Separately, it'd be reassuring to see the loops around this to check there's nothing constant across iterations.

Comment: @Tony Delroy: I could store pre-calculated sign values, however, that would increase the table size from 2k to 4k with possible negative effects on cache hits. I will try it later tonight. The only thing that changes across loops is `bits`.

Comment: If the `int` type is less than 64 bits, there are a number of optimizations available, since many bits would be lost in the calculations.  But I assume it is a 64-bit or greater architecture?

Comment: "The only thing that changes across loops is bits"... if that's true (in the sense that `x` and `r` are not calculated from bits), then the only variable in the result `((x << 18) * sign) | r` is the sign, and if instead of calculating it the way you do now you could shift '1' left so you can directly `&` with `bits`, using that to choose between values of `(x << 18) | r` and `-(x << 18) | r` precalculated before the loop....

Comment: @TonyDelroy: I was a bit to fast there, `x` and ´r´ is calculated from bits. Sorry for being ambiguous, I'll update my example.

Comment: @wallyk: Your assumption is correct, this is built and run for x64.

Comment: if `sign_offset` is zero, then the `& 0x2` is checking a bit that doesn't exist in the `bits` field, is that correct? If yes, then why no `assert(sign_offset > 0)`?

Comment: If `sign_offset` remains constant across iterations, you can calculate the bitmask with just the correct bit on, and then all you need to do is bitwise-and it with the new bits (in each iteration) to get `sign`.

Comment: `int sign = 1 - (bits >> (63 - sign_offset) & 0x2);` could be reduced to a single bitmask operation using a precalculated bitmask table

Comment: @EranZimmerman: `sign_offset` is calculated from bits. I'm starting to see the problem with trying to provide minimalistic samples.

Comment: @Andrey, I'm sure the CPU will calculate `(63 - sign_offset)` faster then `lookup[sign_offset]`.

Comment: @WouterH: yes, but `bits >> (63 - sign_offset)` may be not faster

Comment: @Andrey: that makes 2 assembler instructions

Comment: @Andrey Dont forget that `bits` changes in each iteration...

Comment: @ronag Is it possible to know all the `bits`' values in advance, i.e. make all (or some) of the calculations "offline"?

Comment: @EranZimmerman: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I made the observation, that the logical right shift is faster than the [arithmetic right shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift). I don't know if this is true for left shift operations, but you could try it by changing `x` to `unsigned`.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: According to the IA32/64 Optimization Reference, the SAR/SAL/SHL/SHR instructions all have the same latency and throughput. Other processors may vary.

Comment: @ronag: You say the get_ functions are table lookups that use a 16bit index - this would cause a huge slow down as random access to memory is a very slow operation. What, exactly, do those functions do?

Comment: This is for Huffman decoding, right?

Comment: @harold: Yes, huffman decoding.

Comment: @Skizz: The lookup is optimized, it doesn't use a `[1<<16]` table. It is done with 3 different tables which are chosen according to if/else branches based on `bits`

Comment: @ronag: I would still bet that the get_ functions are the slow down. The compiler is re-ordering the calls into the hotspot area. Three table lookups is probably much worse than a single lookup in a large table. Memory access is usually the slowest thing that can be done in a program, it can take anything from a few cycles to thousands of cycles depending on what memory is being read.

Comment: Is the size of entry.r dependent on the table used? Also, what is in the is_tableX and get_tableX_index functions?

Comment: The entry.r (now called r_offset), is always the same number of bits (as defined by the entry struct), the value itself depends on the table and the bits variable. The is_tablex/is_in_tablex is simply bit shift/masking and comparison against a maximal value and get_tablex_index is a bit shift/masking to get the index used for the table.

Comment: Changing the `int tableX [...]` to a 16 bit array would reduce the potential for memory cache misses since the cache can hold twice the number of entries.

Comment: Why would changing it to a 16 bit array reduce memory cache misses? That would require 65 times more memory for the array? From what I understand the only advantage of using a 16 bit array would be to avoid the branches and potential branch misspredictions.

Comment: @ronag: By 16 bit I meant an array of 16 bit values rather than 32 bit values since the entry structure is 16 bits. Also, you are testing a release build and not a debug build aren't you? The assembler looks too literal for a release build.

Comment: @Skizz: Good idea. It is indeed release build. Though I think I have solved the sign calculation, see my answer below.

Comment: @Skizz: This is right for 32 bit shifts on 32 bit architecture and 64 bit shifts on 64 bit architecture. But 64 bit shifts on 32 bit architecture are software shifts implemented in the functions `_allshl` and `_allshr`. But for OP it probably doesn't matter because his program runs on a 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the fastest solution:

```
*result++ = (_rotl64(bits, sign_offset) << 31) | (x << 18) | (r << 0); // 32 bits
```

And then correct x depending on whether the sign bit is set or not on the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

*I overlooked the fact that the sign is +/-1, so I'm correcting my answer.*

Assuming that `mask` is an array with properly defined bitmasks for all possible values of `sign_offset`, this approach might be faster

```
  bool sign = (bits & mask[sign_offset]) != 0;
  __int64 result = r;
  if (sign)
    result |= -(x << 18);
  else
    result |= x << 18;
```

The code generated by VC2010 optimized build

OP code (11 instructions)

```
; 23   :   __int64 sign = 1 - (bits >> (63 - sign_offset) & 0x2);

    mov rax, QWORD PTR bits$[rsp]
    mov ecx, 63                 ; 0000003fH
    sub cl, BYTE PTR sign_offset$[rsp]
    mov edx, 1
    sar rax, cl

; 24   :   __int64 result  = ((x << 18) * sign) | r; // 32 bits
; 25   :   std::cout << result;

    and eax, 2
    sub rdx, rax
    mov rax, QWORD PTR x$[rsp]
    shl rax, 18
    imul    rdx, rax
    or  rdx, QWORD PTR r$[rsp]
```

My code (8 instructions)

```
; 34   :   bool sign = (bits & mask[sign_offset]) != 0;

    mov r11, QWORD PTR sign_offset$[rsp]

; 35   :   __int64 result = r;
; 36   :   if (sign)
; 37   :     result |= -(x << 18);

    mov rdx, QWORD PTR x$[rsp]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR mask$[rsp+r11*8]
    shl rdx, 18
    test    rax, QWORD PTR bits$[rsp]
    je  SHORT $LN2@Test1
    neg rdx
$LN2@Test1:

; 38   :   else
; 39   :     result |= x << 18;

    or  rdx, QWORD PTR r$[rsp]
```

*EDIT* by Skizz

To get rid of branch:

```
shl rdx, 18
lea rbx,[rdx*2]
test rax, QWORD PTR bits$[rsp]
cmove rbx,0
sub rdx,rbx
or rdx, QWORD PTR r$[rsp]
```

Comment: @harold: Neither do I, but it's the shortest assembly code I could obtain so far...

Comment: Adding another memory lookup will make the code slower than just working out the bit position and using the `bt` instruction. Memory access is almost always slower than running a few instructions through the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some equivalent transformations:

```
int sign = 1 - (bits >> (63 - sign_offset) & 0x2);
int result  = ((x << 18) * sign) | r; // 32 bits
```

Perhaps the processor will find shifting 32-bit values cheaper -- replace the definition of `HIDWORD` with whatever leads to direct access to the high-order DWORD without shifting. Also, for preparation of the next step, let's rearrange the shifting in the second assignment:

```
#define HIDWORD(q) ((uint32_t)((q) >> 32))
int sign = 1 - (HIDWORD(bits) >> (31 - sign_offset) & 0x2);
int result  = ((x * sign) << 18) | r; // 32 bits
```

Observe that, in two-s complement, `q * (-1)` equals `~q + 1`, or `(q ^ -1) - (-1)`, while `q * 1` equals `(q ^ 0) - 0`. This justifies the second transformation which gets rid of the nasty multiplication:

```
int mask = -(HIDWORD(bits) >> (32 - sign_offset) & 0x1);
int result  = (((x ^ mask) - mask) << 18) | r; // 32 bits
```

Now let's rearrange shifting again:

```
int mask = (-(HIDWORD(bits) >> (32 - sign_offset) & 0x1)) << 18;
int result  = (((x << 18) ^ mask) - mask) | r; // 32 bits
```

Recall the identity concerning `-` and `~`:

```
int mask = (~(HIDWORD(bits) >> (32 - sign_offset) & 0x1) + 1) << 18;
```

Shift rearrangement again:

```
int mask = (~(HIDWORD(bits) >> (32 - sign_offset) & 0x1)) << 18 + (1 << 18);
```

Who can finally unfiddle this? (Are the transformations corect anyway?)

(Note that only profiling on a real CPU can 
assess the performance. Measures like instruction count won't do. I am not even sure that the transformations helped at all.)

Comment: Nice, actually I think it might be possible to change `~bits`, to just `bits`, and then let the GPU invert the sign of the value during the next processing stage. I will try this tonight.

Comment: The first transformation is just wrong, I thought it was `& 0x1` but it is `& 0x2`. What happens with the `result` anyway if `sign` is `-1`?

Comment: If sign is -1 then the sign bit in result is set and the complement of x is stored, i.e. negative x is stored into result.

Comment: I was wondering if the bitwise OR is still valid, but it seems like it is.

Comment: I compiled it and got 13 instructions. The 2nd code snippet is also 13 instructions and has a small mistake

Comment: @Andrey: Care to explain the small mistake?

Comment: @user946850: `-(HIDWORD(bits) >> (32 - sign_offset) & 0x1);`: minus is applied to unsigned type

Comment: @Andrey: Right. A statical code analyzer will probably choke on this, but the compiler and the CPU should swallow it.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the sign, I would suggest this:

```
int sign = (int)(((int64_t)(bits << sign_offset)) >> 63);
```

Which is only 2 instructions (`shl` and `sar`).

If `sign_offset` is one bigger than I expected:

```
int sign = (int)(((int64_t)(bits << (sign_offset - 1))) >> 63);
```

Which is still not bad. Should be only 3 instructions.

That gives an answer as 0 or -1, with which you can do this:

```
(*result++) = (((x << 18) ^ sign) - sign) | r;
```

Comment: That won't work, since the sign will be shifted out, should be `bits << (sign_offset-1)`.

Comment: It would be shifted out? What exactly does `get_sign_offset` return then, not the number of leading zero's?

Comment: `sign_bit_index = (63 - sign_offset)`.

Answer (score 1):

Memory access is usually the root of all optimisation problems on modern CPUs. You are being misled by the performance tools as to where the slow down is happening. The compiler is probably re-ordering the code to something like this:-

```
int sign    = 1 - (bits >> (63 - get_sign_offset(bits)) & 0x2);
(*result++) = ((get_x(bits) << 18) * sign) | (r += get_r_offset(bits));
```

or even:-

```
(*result++) = ((get_x(bits) << 18) * (1 - (bits >> (63 - get_sign_offset(bits)) & 0x2))) | (r += get_r_offset(bits));
```

This would highlight the lines you identified as being the hotspot.

I would look at the way you organise your memory and the what the various get_ functions do. Can you post the get_ functions at all?

Comment: I cannot post the code as is, but I can write a variant of it and post that, I will do this later.

Comment: There is no re-ordering, due to the branches which you can now see.

Comment: @ronag: I wouldn't be so sure of that, compilers can do the most unexpected (and usually more optimal) operations on the code. The conditional part could still be reordered into the hotspot area, the only way to know for sure is to look at the assembly output - there's usually a compiler option to write the assembly version to file, otherwise the debugger may be able to find the code.

Comment: I used the debugger and updated my post with the release assembly generated.